# Multiple fields populated by the same search form

Tags: jsf

I have a multiple fields that needs to be populated with the same value type. Finding the value to those fields requires a quick search.  So next to each field I'm thinking of a button calling a simple search form.  So basically :

```
Field 1 [...]
Field 2 [...]
Field 3 [...]
...
```

Clicking on the `[...]` button calls the search form ideally in a modal window through a `<p:dialog>` to prevent unnecessary page navigation.  When the value is selected in the search form and the modal window is closed, the according `Field X` value is set.

So in short I would like to be able to drop this `[...]` button wherever I want and somehow *link* it to the field I want to populate.

How can I do that?  As far as I know bean injection can't work with this.  I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar like this:

A composite component for your button: inpbutton.xhtml

```
<composite:interface componentType="inpbutton">
    <composite:attribute name="value"     type="java.lang.Object"/>

...
<composite:implementation>
    <h:commandButton value="..." actionListener="#{cc.action()}"/>
```

The corresponding class: Inpbutton.java

```
@FacesComponent("inpbutton")
public class Inpbutton extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    public void action() {
        ValueExpression vx = getValueExpression("value");
        getBean(InpDialog.class).openDialog(vx);
    }
}

// static utilities from elsewhere

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static <T> T uncheckedCast(Object obj) {
        return (T) obj;
}
public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> cls) {
    BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    Bean<T> bean = uncheckedCast(bm.getBeans(cls).iterator().next());
    CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return uncheckedCast(bm.getReference(bean, cls, ctx));
}
```

The xhtml:

```
<h:inputText value="databean.entry1"/>
<X:inpbutton value="databean.entry1"/>
```

maybe you combine the input field and the button in the composite component.

And the bean for the search dialog: InpDialog.java

```
ValueExpression vx = null;

public void openDialog(ValueExpression val) {
    vx = val;
    // open the modal dialog with button -> dialogWorker()
}

public void dialogWorker() {
     // do the stuff

     // set the field X value
     if(vx!=null)
         vx.setValue(theResult);
}
```